# using joins or unions for different filtering

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I have 3 tables.

- tb_post: id, user, text and
- tb_follow: id, user, followed_user and
- tb_share: id, fk_post_id, user(who shared the post)

so user01 want to retrieve all posts for users followed by user01 + all posts shared by
users that are folllowed by user01

edited: how can i get that? i tried this query:

```
select * from post 
left join follow on post_user = follow_user 
left join share on follow_user = share_user
```

But I got only the first part.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson i used left joins (select * from post left join follow on post_user = follow_user left join share on follow_user = share_user) but i get only the first part

Comment: @user why? the question is clear. i put my tables and what i want to get!

Comment: @usr what are you on about mate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it without using a union.  Performance wise, you are basically running two queries. Be sure to have appropriate fields indexed and you should be fine.

```
SELECT tb_post.id, tb_post.text
FROM tb_post INNER JOIN tb_follow ON tb_post.user = tb_follow.followed_user
WHERE (((tb_follow.user)=100))
ORDER BY tb_post.id
UNION SELECT tb_post.id, tb_post.text
FROM (tb_share INNER JOIN tb_follow ON tb_share.user = tb_follow.followed_user) INNER JOIN tb_post ON tb_share.fk_post_id = tb_post.id
WHERE (((tb_follow.user)=100))
ORDER BY tb_post.id;
```

Comment: it worked. my question was how to get that and is it possible without using a union. you answered all that with the performance thing . thanks Nick. Constructive answer :D

Comment: This syntax doesn't work - you can only have one `ORDER BY` in a `UNION`. Also what is ((the (purpose of ((all (of (the)) parentheses))))?

Comment: yes. you are right. i used only one order by. parentheses are just for clarifying i believe

Comment: @Roobah a) he wasn't asking you about the parentheses, and b) they are actually used for scope resolution and for operator evaluation order (such as if you use an OR clause). In this case, they really don't do a lot of good, as far as I can tell.